# FFMPEG Reducing output filesize in my unique situation

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have an image, bg.jpg, and a mp4 video file (video.mp4) that is 20 seconds long.

I want to loop the image for 2 hours, because it will be the background image for a long music track.

I create a 1 second video of this frame, so that I can then use -stream_loop -1 to get to my desired duration.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i bg.jpg -t 1 temp.mp4
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i temp.mp4 -c copy -t 02:00:00 out.mp4
```

But now, I want to overlay video.mp4 onto out.mp4.  To do this will require reencoding the entire 2 hour video, just to overlay 20 seconds of it.  There must be a better way.

Things I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i bg.jpg -t 20 temp.mp4
ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay" overlaid.mp4
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 overlaid.mp4 -c copy -t 02:00:00 out.mp4
```

This is fast, but the problem it, I only wanted the overlay to occur once, not be looped for the entire 2 hours.

So I then tried the following:

Loop bg.jpg for 20 seconds and overlay video.mp4.  Then stream loop a 1 second video of bg.jpg for 01:59:40.  Concat this with the video containing the overlay.

I also began researching variable frame rates, because this is so wasteful to have the entire video at 29.97 fps, considering the vast majority of the duration will be simply a single frame (Except for the first 20 seconds, with the overlaid video that does include motion).

Can someone tell me the best method to achieve what I am looking for?  I can provide more information upon request, if needed.

Thank you!

Comment: Doing the overlay and the loop in one command, may solve the re-encoding issue. About the variable frame rates, it is not supported by most video players. There are "playlist" kind of solution, when the input is in multiple mp4 (or m3u8 segments) files. Do some reassert to see if you can use something like HLS with different frame rates per segment.

Answer (score 1):

#### Creating the loop

You can spare **all** of the intermediate steps of looping the video:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i bg.png -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -t 02:00:00 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,5,10)'" -c:a copy out.mp4`

**Explanation:**

`-loop 1` will enable looping **only for the next** input file.
We will take the image file as input after with `-i test.png` our `-loop` argument.
`-loop` takes a boolean as parameter.

With `-t hh:mm:ss` we specify the length of the output video.

`[0:v][1:v]` will specify the used video streams.

`overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,5,10)` tells ffmpeg to overlay the second video stream at coordinates `0:0` between second 5 and 10 (`between(t,5,10)`) of the output video.

`-c:a copy` tells ffmpeg to copy the audio into the container, without reencoding.

#### Reducing the filesize

As Rotem already pointed out, variable framerate can lead to problems with certain players. It can also lead to other problems like the audio drifting.

I would suggest you use a good video encoder like h265 instead.

Depending on your audio file it could also make sense to reencode the audio with FLAC if you prefer good quality or mp3 if you prefer a lower filesize.

##### H.265

With h265 we can use a variable bitrate to lower the filesize while maintaining a constant quality.
For that we can use the `-crf` parameter. You can set it to anywhere from 0 to 51, where a lower value would be better quality and a higher value would be a lower quality. The default is 28.

We can modify the ffmpeg command further to add h265 encoding:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i bg.png -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -t 02:00:00 -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,5,10)'" -c:a copy out.mp4`

Comment: Thanks, but the first command in your post runs terribly slow, even when using GPU acceleration.  It will encode the entire 2 hours, just for a 5 second overlay :(  Will give the H.265 suggestion a try shortly.

Comment: Using filter options like overlay **will** reencode the whole video. h265 will also  probably be slower than whatever other video codec you are using.  If your intention is to only cut down on the encoding time, and the video you want to overlay will be the same size as the image, you could cut three parts with their respective lengths, merge them together with mkverge and add the audio. The question is at which point your research takes more time than the encoding itself. h265 with GPU acceleration should encode with around 90fps, meaning 40min for a 2 hour video.

Comment: Appreciate the response.  I am trying something new:  I am looping image.jpg for 1 second and outputting as mp4, then stream looping that output for the duration of the video I am overlaying (20 seconds).  I could then stream loop the 1 second mp4 for 2 hours - 20 seconds.  Finally, concat the 20 second video with the longer one.  It seems to me, this is the most efficient way to reduce encoding time in my specific use case.  I believe concat uses stream copying as well, which is the reason for this approach.  I am going to give this a try tonight.